# SQL Server 2008 XML query issue

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, visual-studio-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise + VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net + IIS 7.0 to develop a simple web application. In my database table, I have a XML type column. The content is like below,

I want to get AdditionalInfoList of all rows in the table if Title contains "software engineer" or Info contains "Software Development". My question is how to write such query efficiently?

```
<People>
  <Item Name="Username" Value="George" />
  <Item Name="Info" Value="Software Development Information" />
  <Item Name="Title" Value="Software Engineer in Backend" />
  <AdditionalInfoList>
    <AdditionalInfoListItem Guid="xxx" type="type1" />
    <AdditionalInfoListItem Guid="yyy" type="type2" />
  </AdditionalInfoList>
</People>
```

Comment: My current solution is read all XML into an XML string, then parse XML string, which I think is less efficient. I want to find a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    t.ID, -- or whatever you need from the table where the XML is located
    tbl.People.query('AdditionalInfoList')
FROM
    dbo.YourTable  t
CROSS APPLY
    t.(xmlcolumn).nodes('/People') AS Tbl(People)
WHERE
    tbl.People.value('(Item[@Name="Info"]/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') LIKE '%Software Development%'
    OR
    tbl.People.value('(Item[@Name="Title"]/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') LIKE '%Software Engineer%'
```

That should give you all the entries you're interested in.

**Explanations**:

The `CROSS APPLY` creates a "dummy" table which you need to give a name to - here: `Tbl(People)`. What that name is doesn't really matter, and it's not case sensitive, so `Tbl` and `tbl` are identical.

If you want to Guid and the type as separate values from the `<AdditionalInfoList>`, you need to use this query here:

```
SELECT
    t.ID,
    --tbl.People.value('(Item[@Name="Info"]/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'Info',
    --tbl.People.value('(Item[@Name="Title"]/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'Title'
    Adtl.Info.value('(@Guid)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'GUID',
    Adtl.Info.value('(@type)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS 'Type'
FROM
    @table t
CROSS APPLY 
    t.xmlcolumn.nodes('/People') AS Tbl(People)
CROSS APPLY 
    Tbl.People.nodes('AdditionalInfoList/AdditionalInfoListItem') AS Adtl(Info)
WHERE
    Tbl.People.value('(Item[@Name="Info"]/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') LIKE '%Software Development%'
    OR
    Tbl.People.value('(Item[@Name="Title"]/@Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') LIKE '%Software Engineer%'
```

You basically have to do a second CROSS APPLY (that'll hurt your performance!) to get the "additional info" list for each of the entries from `Tbl.Person` and extract the Guid and the type value from that.

Check out the [SQL Server 2005 XQuery and XML DML](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/050803.htm) introduction - about in the middle of the article, there's a section on how to use the `.nodes()` function. Very helpful!

Comment: TBL is what? And how to get GUID and type from retrieved information for each matched row?

Comment: For TBL I am confused because you are using both TBL and "tbl".

Comment: Thank you, do you suppose your method is much faster than my previous solution, and why?

Comment: Thanks for your update. I am new to CROSS APPLY, I think Cross apply should join a table with a function, correct? But in your sample code, there is no function to join?

Comment: I have tried your first method (the first sample), and it works cool! My last question is, for this column you returned -- tbl.People.query('AdditionalInfoList'), from client side (e.g. ADO.Net which invokes store procedure) how to treat its type? As string?

Comment: @George2: I would believe this would be much faster, yes - and much more practical, too. Why? Because the XQuery stuff is quite nicely optimized in SQL Server, and being able to retrieve the actual values from the structures rather than parsing strings is just more robust, I think.

Comment: @George2: CROSS APPLY works against a set of data - e.g. a set of rows from your function, or the set of "pseudo-rows" from the XQuery `.nodes()` function - and that `.nodes()` is indeed a function, too! It returns "one row" for each entry in the XML that is matched by the XPath expression in the `.nodes()` function.

Comment: Thanks Marc, for the first sample, how to treat the returned column " tbl.People.query('AdditionalInfoList')"? Is it a string from ADO.Net client side or something else?

Comment: @George2: yes, you can read it back as a string, and then load it into a XmlDocument or XDocument (Linq-to-XML) - whatever works for you